# Vectorized Conditional Random Matching

Tags: r

I want to create conditional random pairs without using for-loops so I can use the code with large datasets. At first, I create rows with unique IDs and randomly assign two different "types" to my rows:

```
df<-data.frame(id=1:10,type=NA,partner=NA)
df[sample(df$id,nrow(df)/2),"type"]<-1 ##random 50% type 1
df[which(is.na(df$type)==TRUE),"type"]<-2 ##other 50% type 2
df
   id type partner
1   1    2      NA
2   2    1      NA
3   3    1      NA
4   4    1      NA
5   5    2      NA
6   6    1      NA
7   7    1      NA
8   8    2      NA
9   9    2      NA
10 10    2      NA
```

Now I want them to receive a random partner of the opposite type. So I randomize my type 1 IDs and match them to some type 2 IDs like so:

```
df$partner[which(df$type==2)]<-sample(df$id[which(df$type==1)],
                                            nrow(df)/2) 

df
   id type partner
1   1    2       4
2   2    1      NA
3   3    1      NA
4   4    1      NA
5   5    2       2
6   6    1      NA
7   7    1      NA
8   8    2       6
9   9    2       3
10 10    2       7
```

And that's where I'm stuck. For some reason I can't think of a vectorized way to tell R "take the IDs of type 1, look where these IDs are in `df$partner` and return the corresponding row ID as `df$partner` instead of NA".

One example for a for-loop for conditional random pairing can be found here: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232107/conditional-random-matching-from-one-data-frame-into-another-data-frame)

I'm pretty sure that that's very basic and doable, however, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want the type 1 and type 2 matched together to have each other's id in their respective partner entries. Fully vectorized solution.

```
# Define number of ids
n = 100

# Generate startingn data frame
df = data.frame(id = 1:n, type = NA, partner = NA)

# Generate the type column
df$type[(a<-sample(df$id, n/2))] = 1
df$type[(b<-setdiff(1:100, a))] = 2

# Select a random partner id from the other type
df$partner[a] = sample(df$id[b])
# Fill in partner values based on previous line
df$partner[b] = df$id[match(df$id[b], df$partner)]
```

Output:

```
 id type partner
  1    2      11
  2    1      13
  3    2      19
  4    2      10
  5    1      17
  6    2      28
  7    2      27
  8    2      21
  9    1      22
 10    1       4
 11    1       1
 12    2      20
 13    2       2
 14    2      25
 15    2      24
 16    2      30
 17    2       5
 18    2      29
 19    1       3
 20    1      12
 21    1       8
 22    2       9
 23    2      26
 24    1      15
 25    1      14
 26    1      23
 27    1       7
 28    1       6
 29    1      18
 30    1      16
```